# What is this squeezable hand tool with various inserts?

Tags: tools, identify-a-tool

[image]

Trying to figure out what this is for?

Comment: A couple more pictures of it opened will help.  Right now a squeeze/stapler or a multi tool handle for wrench/ratchet.

Comment: Or something for co-ax connectors. Really need the photo of it opened. Were there any other pieces with the tool?

Comment: might be a small gauge sheetmetal nibbler

Comment: Is there a company name on it?

Answer (score 36):

This is a compression tool for terminating F connectors on coaxial cable, for cable TV and satellite applications.

It looks [identical to the one from Harbor Freight](https://www.harborfreight.com/coaxial-cable-compression-tool-57195.html).
[image: Image of Coaxial compression tool with connectors]
(Harbor Freight catalog photo)

The active mechanism is in the top handle in the photo. The connector body is placed between the cylindrical piston and the red restraining part, with the coax fed out the back. When the tool is squeezed, the piston lowers and compresses the connector axially, causing the connector's main body to slide into the sleeve on the back of the connector. As this happens, the sleeve swages down/compresses the body of the connector radially, restraining the cable in the connector.

Comment: Confirmed - I own one.  They're fiddly to use and you have to faff around getting all the braid, insulator and wire exactly the right length.  After that its easy.   But the crimp plugs have a cost that adds up, and also subtle variations so that some other brand's crimps won't fit another brand's tool.

Comment: Also they're a bit unusual because there's a radial compression function in the head, like any other similarly shaped tool, but in the handle is a second compression that works lengthwise.